# Combo Box PHP with MySQL using data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I am trying to make a combo box in PHP using data from a MySQL table.

```
$sql = "SELECT FacultyName FROM faculties";

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     while ( $array[] = mysqli_fetch_object ( $query ) );

array_pop ( $array );

....

<select name="Faculty">
     <?php foreach ( $array as $option ) : ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $option->FacultyName; ?>"><?php echo $option->FacultyName ; ?></option> 
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

The idea is that my combo box remains empty, although when using print_r($array) I get the following result

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FacultyName] => Architecture and Urban Planning
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FacultyName] => Civil engineering
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FacultyName] => Computer Science and Automation
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FacultyName] => Electrical Engineering
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FacultyName] => Electronics, Telecommunications and Information Technology
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FacultyName] => Machine Building
    )
```

)

[image]

Comment: If your array really does contain that data, your code works fine: https://3v4l.org/D5jSb. So you must be overwriting it, or never actually getting to the loop.

Comment: Indeed I think it never enters the loop. I also tried changing my code and ended up with this      <?php
     
     $sqlQ = "SELECT FacultyName FROM faculties";

     if ( $result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlQ) )
         
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)); 
         echo "<option value="'.$row.'">".$row."</option>";
        
     ?>   but it says that variable row is undefined, how could i solve this?

Comment: You have a `;` after the `while` that shouldn't be there, also your quotes around `$row` are the wrong way around. Try `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) echo "<option value='".$row."'>".$row."</option>";`